# How to count number of unique items with conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in my mongoDB like this:

```
db.x.insert({"time" : ISODate("2014-02-29T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "3" });
db.x.insert({"time" : ISODate("2014-02-29T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "2" });
...
```

and I have an aggregate function to calculate the activity in certain timespans,

```
db.x.aggregate([{
    "$group":{
     "_id":
         {"$cond":[
             {"$and":[
                 {"$gte": ["$time", ISODate("2014-02-15T00:00:00Z")]},
                 {"$lt" : ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-01T00:00:00Z")]}
             ]},
             "season1",
             {"$cond":[
                 {"$and":[
                      {"$gte": ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-01T00:00:00Z")]},
                      {"$lt" : ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-15T00:00:00Z")]}
                  ]},
                  "season2",
                  null
             ]}
        ]},
        "count": {"$sum": 1}
    }},
    {"$sort": { "_id": 1 }}
])
```

It works fine with results like this

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "season1",
            "count" : 7
        },
        {
            "_id" : "season2",
            "count" : 7
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but I'm really stuck on how to calculate how many unique users there were in each timespan?
Is there a way of doing it without making a call to mongo for each timeinterval?

Comment: Where were you at with this. You got one answer, and one misguided one. It should show how to get the unique users within your results

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not far off your approach. The operator you were probably missing is the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator, which is used in the stages like so ( with also a bit more of an explain on what you have done ) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([

   {"$group":{
        "_id": {

            // This is conditionally setting the _id
            "$cond":[
                // Where between this range
                {"$and":[
                    {"$gte": ["$time", ISODate("2014-02-15T00:00:00Z")]},
                    {"$lt" : ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-01T00:00:00Z")]}
                ]},
                // Set to season1
                "season1",
                // Otherwise ...  
                {"$cond":[
                    // if between this range
                    {"$and":[
                        {"$gte": ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-01T00:00:00Z")]},
                        {"$lt" : ["$time", ISODate("2014-03-15T00:00:00Z")]}
                    ]},
                    // Then it's season2
                    "season2",
                    // otherwise we don't know what it is
                    null
                ]}
            ]
        },
        // Just counting the items in the results
        "count": {"$sum": 1},
        // Now get the users
        "users": {"$addToSet": "$user" }          // Just the unique ones
    }},

    // De-normalise the users from the set
    {"$unwind": "$users" },

    // Now we want to sum things again
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "_$id",
        "count": {"$first": "$count" },
        "userCount": {"$sum": 1 }
    }}

])
```

So after we add to a **set** which makes things unique, the array gets **unwound** which makes things like the document they were before, except with **unique** users now.

The final step is that we just **count** the user entries by summing the values of `1` for each item. All the `userCount` entries are the same, so when we `$group` you just take one of them.

And there finally is the end result, also including the count of **unique** users.